# Scala Play - How to Modify Cookie setting value before response goes out?

Tags: scala, cookies, playframework

I have a project on a 2.7.3 version of Scala Play framework. I need to address being able to set a cookie's Samesite value to 'None'. Currently in 2.7.3 you can only set to 'Lax' or 'Strict' via an enumeration. The ability to set the value to 'None' [has been backported for 2.7.x](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/9613) but not yet released.

I need to address this now and can't wait for a future release. I am having a hard time figuring out how to accomplish setting a Cookie's Samesite value to 'None' within the given framework.

In order to modify the response result in a filter, I see I could call result.withCookie() which takes one or more play.api.mvc.cookie. I've tried to extend and modify [play.api.mvc.cookie](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.7.3/core/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Cookie.scala) but the Samesite class is sealed abstract inside the Cookie class.

I thought I might be able to use an Essential Filter or an Action to modify the cookie right before the response goes out but don't see a way to get at an existing CSRF cookie or the Play_Session cookie and modify it.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Not familiar with the framework, but a few things that have worked in similar situations: send the `Set-cookie` yourself instead of using the cookie functionality. Alternatively, alter the cookie at some kind of proxy level, such as Apache. I've got an early Cloudflare Worker example here: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/samesite-examples/blob/cloudflare-worker/cloudflare-worker.md

Comment: Thanks @rowan_m - I think we could use a proxy like this. Was hoping for another solution as I have another team that this isn't an option for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the workaround for this is probably to either use a proxy as @rowan_m mentions. Fortunately Lightbend got back to me and will be releasing their 2.8 version very soon - which I verified in the RC solved the issue using config settings: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/9613#issuecomment-555305142